# Lista ul no se adapta al tamaño de contenedor padre

Tags: html, css, less

He creado una lista ul, dentro de un div.

HTML

```
<div class="servicios">
                                <ul class="list-servicios">
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 adultos</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 niños</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Habitación estandar</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
                                    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 noches</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Esta lista puede ser mas grande y contener muchos más elementos, pero el contenedor padre no puede exceder los 152px de height.

¿Existe alguna forma de adaptar la lista, en caso de crecer que los elementos se acomoden en otra fila?

o alguna otra alternativa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando dices otra fila entiendo que te refieres a otra columna, o sea que la lista llega hasta abajo y continua a la derecha.

Si es así la forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es usar `flexbox`. Se le da direccion de columna para que ordene los elementos de arriba a abajo y la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap` para que los elementos salten de columna al llegar al final de su contenedor:

```css
.list-servicios {
  max-height: 152px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicios">
  <ul class="list-servicios">
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 adultos</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 niños</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Habitación estandar</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 noches</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 adultos</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 niños</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Habitación estandar</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 noches</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 adultos</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 niños</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Habitación estandar</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> Plan alimenticio</li>
    <li><i class="fh-icon fh-icon-badge"></i> 2 noches</li>
</div>
```

Comment: esto, es lo que exactamente necesitaba, muchas gracias, por la explicación